# Read list written in different ways from file

Tags: python, list, file, io, user-input

I need a way to read lists stored in a file in several different ways. I'm trying to think of all the ways a user might think of storing a list inside a file, and correctly interpret it as such.

Here's an example input file with lists written differently.

```
# in_file.dat

# List 1 (enclosing brackets, comma separated, spaces after commas)
[0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1.5]

# List 2 (enclosing parenthesis, comma separated, no spaces or some spaces after commas)
(0.5,0.2,0.6,0.9, 1.5)

# List 3 (enclosing keys, mixed commas and semi-colons, mixed no-spaces and spaces)
{0.5,0.2,0.6;0.9;1.5}

# List 4 (single item)
[0.6]

# List 5 (space separated elements)
[2.3 5. 0.6 1.2 0.0 3.1]
```

Each line should be correctly read as a list resulting in:

```
ls_1 = [0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1.5]
ls_2 = [0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1.5]
ls_3 = [0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1.5]
ls_4 = [0.6]
ls_5 = [2.3, 5., 0.6, 1.2, 0.0, 3.1]
```

The usual way I read files is with

```
# Read data from file.
with open('in_file.dat', "r") as f_dat:
    # Iterate through each line in the file.
    for line in f_dat:
        # Skip comments
        if not line.startswith("#") and line.strip() != '':
            # Read list stored in line.
            ls_X = ??
```

Is there some general way I can use to force python to interpret the line as a list?

Comment: You don't want `ls_1`, `ls_2` ... `ls_6`. Use a dictionary instead.

Comment: @Matthias I don't see how a dictionary would solve my problem here. Would you care to expand?

Comment: For the most part you have to make some assumptions about how the user is going to enter data, it's hard make a general rule. That being said, for your problem, I'd turn all non numeric and non decimal characters into spaces and do a .split() on the line.

Comment: @Gabriel: The dictionary won't help you parsing (that's why I wrote a _comment_ and not an _answer_). My comment is about inventing new variable names during runtime, which is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use re instead if you are sure that each line will just have sequence of numbers

```
import re
lines=[]
for l in f_dat:
    if l and l[0]!='#':
        lines.append([float(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9.]+',l)])
print lines
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: All good answers. I'm selecting this one because it's simple and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import re
with open('in_file.dat', "r") as f_dat:
    for line in f_dat:
      if not line.startswith("#") and line.strip() != '':
          parts = re.split('[, ;]', line[1:-1])  # removes first and last char
          ls_X = filter(lambda x: x!="", parts)  # removes any empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this. This will work for nested structures as well:

```
from ast import literal_eval
import re
from string import maketrans

table = maketrans(';,{}()', '  [][]')
with open('file.txt', "r") as f_dat:
    for line in f_dat:
        if not line.startswith("#") and line.strip() != '':
            line = re.sub(r'\s+', ',', line.strip().translate(table))
            try:
                print literal_eval(line)
            except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
                pass
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> !cat file.txt
# in_file.dat

# List 1 (enclosing brackets, comma separated, spaces after commas)
[0.5,    0.2, 0.6,              [0.9, 1.5]]

# List 2 (enclosing parenthesis, comma separated, no spaces or some spaces after commas)
(0.5,0.2,0.6,0.9, 1.5)

# List 3 (enclosing keys, mixed commas and semi-colons, mixed no-spaces and spaces)
{0.5,0.2,0.6;0.9;1.5;{1, [2, 3; 100 200]}}

# List 4 (single item)
[0.6]

# List 5 (space separated elements)
[2.3 5. 0.6 1.2 0.0 3.1 [10 20 {50, [60]}] ]

>>> %run so.py
[0.5, 0.2, 0.6, [0.9, 1.5]]
[0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1.5]
[0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1.5, [1, [2, 3, 100, 200]]]
[0.6]
[2.3, 5.0, 0.6, 1.2, 0.0, 3.1, [10, 20, [50, [60]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> file
'[0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1.5]\n(0.5,0.2,0.6,0.9, 1.5)\n{0.5,0.2,0.6;0.9;1.5}\n[0.6]\n[2.3 5. 0.6 1.2 0.0 3.1]'
>>> for line in file.split('\n'):
...     print re.split(r"[,\s;]\s*",re.sub(r"[{}()\[\]]",'',line))
... 
['0.5', '0.2', '0.6', '0.9', '1.5']
['0.5', '0.2', '0.6', '0.9', '1.5']
['0.5', '0.2', '0.6', '0.9', '1.5']
['0.6']
['2.3', '5.', '0.6', '1.2', '0.0', '3.1']
```